# Create an Athena Table over S3 bucket using CREATE TABLE EXTERNAL command with AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-cdk

I am new to AWS CDK and would like to know how to create an *Athena table over an S3 bucket* without using a Crawler. I want to write an SQL statement to create the table using **CREATE TABLE EXTERNAL** query and deploy it using AWS CDK. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we need is create a database and table in Glue. Documentation for Glue is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-glue-readme.html)

`CREATE TABLE EXTERNAL` will simply do exact same thing, creating table in Glue pointing to S3 location, which can be queried in Athena.

Here is the sample CDK code

```
const myDatabase = new glue.Database(this, "MyS3Db", {
  databaseName: "my_s3_database",
});

new glue.Table(this, "MyTable", {
  database: myDatabase,
  tableName: "my_table",
  bucket: new s3.Bucket(this, "bucket-where-source-data-is"),
  columns: [
    {
      name: "col1",
      type: glue.Schema.STRING,
    },
    {
      name: "col2",
      type: glue.Schema.array(glue.Schema.STRING),
      comment: "col2 is an array of strings",
    },
  ],
  dataFormat: glue.DataFormat.JSON,
});
```